# Sort by divs content (click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that appends the content.

There is only 1 change I need to do, but don't know how.

I want a sort by content of the div every time I click.(ASC to desc or desc to ASC)

What he does now is:

I have 3 divs

```
<div>Others</div>
<div>Girls</div>
<div>Boy</div>
```

if I click it changes in

```
<div>Boy Girls Other</div>
<div>>Boy Girls Other</div>
<div>>Boy Girls Other</div>
```

My code:

```
$("#button-sort").click(function(){
    $(".sorteren div").sort(asc_sort).appendTo('.sorteren');

    function asc_sort(a, b){
        return ($(b).text()) < ($(a).text()) ? 1 : -1;
    }

    function dec_sort(a, b){
        return ($(b).text()) > ($(a).text()) ? 1 : -1;    
    }
});
```

Code that I used before:

```
var mylist = $('.sorteren');
var listitems = mylist.children('div').get();    
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
});

$.each(listitems, function(index, item) {
    mylist.append(item); 
});
```

My div structer is:

```
<div id="drive-content">
  <div class="folderbox">
    <div class="sorteren">
      <div class="items-titel"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="folderbox">
    <div class="sorteren">
      <div class="items-titel"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="folderbox">
    <div class="sorteren">
      <div class="items-titel"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what error do you got?

Comment: It's not the error I need to combine this with click event . If i do that it will only append (like the code does) but instead of append i need just to sort it on asc-desc and desc-asc

Comment: Please create a [MCVE] rather than little snippets than don't quite have enough information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `add/remove` one class to sort asc/desc, and just assign sorted html to one variable and change html of `sorteren` div as that variable.

```js
$("#button-sort").click(function() {
  var sort, el = $('.sorteren')
  sort = el.find('div').sort(el.hasClass('asc') ? dec_sort : asc_sort)
  el.toggleClass('asc')

  function asc_sort(a, b) {
    return ($(b).text()) < ($(a).text()) ? 1 : -1;
  }

  function dec_sort(a, b) {
    return ($(b).text()) > ($(a).text()) ? 1 : -1;
  }

  $(".sorteren").html(sort)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button-sort">sort</button>

<div class="sorteren">
  <div>Others</div>
  <div>Girls</div>
  <div>Boy</div>
</div>
```

In case you have multiple `.sorteren` divs and you want to sort each one you can change code to this.

```js
$("#button-sort").click(function() {
  function asc_sort(a, b) {
    return ($(b).text()) < ($(a).text()) ? 1 : -1;
  }

  function dec_sort(a, b) {
    return ($(b).text()) > ($(a).text()) ? 1 : -1;
  }

  $(".sorteren").each(function() {
    var sort, el = $(this)
    sort = el.find('div').sort(el.hasClass('asc') ? dec_sort : asc_sort)
    el.toggleClass('asc')

    el.html(sort)
  })
})
```

```css
.sorteren {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button-sort">sort</button>

<div class="sorteren">
  <div>Others</div>
  <div>Girls</div>
  <div>Boy</div>
</div>

<div class="sorteren">
  <div>c</div>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a script that makes the divs and the content. On 1 page i will have only 3 divs other page I will have 55 divs with same structure. Thats the reason i can't use this script. And my script will append all the content in 1 div

Comment: Do you mean you have multiple `.sorteren` divs with divs inside and you want all of them sorted when you click on sort button?

Comment: Yes everytime the script makes 1 folder box it contains a div named sorteren with the div named item-title its about the content of the div named item-title

Comment: Nope it doesnt work and no errors i will update my div structure uno momento

Comment: It somehow delete's the entire div with all divs in it

Comment: It's my fault . I made a typo (don't know why he is deleting everything) but thnx to u its working !!! Thnx THNX THNX !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!